# Ordering java linked list alphabetically (dictionary-like)

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

I've been working for hours trying to order a linked list of strings alphabetically (dictionary-like). The given string is lowercase only.
For example, input of: "hello my name is albert" will be sorted in the list as: Node 1: albert,
Node 2: hello,
Node 3: is,
etc..

My code so far reads a string like the example above and insert it as nodes - **unordered**.

I've searched in the web for ways to sort a linked list alphabetically with good performance, and I found **Merge Sort** can be usefull.
I've changed the merge sort to work for string using **compareTo()** but my code returns nullPointerException error in the following line:

```
if(firstList._word.compareTo(secondList._word) < 0){
```

I'm looking for help to fix the following code or another way for sorting a linked list alphabetically (without Collection.sort)

My full code is (after trying to add the merge sort to work with my code):

```
public class TextList
{
    public WordNode _head;

    public TextList() 
    {
    _head = null;
    }

    public TextList (String text)
    {
        this._head = new WordNode();
        int lastIndex = 0;
        boolean foundSpace = false;
        String newString;
        WordNode prev,next;
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            this._head._word = null;
            this._head._next = null;
        }
        else {
        for (int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
        {
                if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
               newString = text.substring(lastIndex,i);
               insertNode(newString);
               // Update indexes
                lastIndex = i;
                // set to true when the string has a space
                foundSpace = true;  
        }
    }
        if (!foundSpace) {
            //If we didnt find any space, set the given word
            _head.setWord(text);
            _head.setNext(null);

        }
        else {
            //Insert last word
            String lastString = text.substring(lastIndex,text.length());
            WordNode lastNode = new WordNode(_head._word,_head._next);
            _head.setNext(new WordNode(lastString,lastNode));

        }

        sortList(_head);

    }
}

      private void insertNode(String word)
      {
      //Create a new node and put the curret node in it
      WordNode newWord = new WordNode(_head._word,_head.getNext());
      //Set the new information in the head
      _head._word = word;
      _head.setNext(newWord);
    }

private WordNode sortList(WordNode start) {
        if (start == null || start._next == null) return start;
        WordNode fast = start;
        WordNode slow = start;
        // get in middle of the list :
        while (fast._next!= null && fast._next._next !=null){
            slow = slow._next; fast = fast._next._next;
        }
        fast = slow._next;
        slow._next=null;
        return mergeSortedList(sortList(start),sortList(fast));
        }

        private WordNode mergeSortedList(WordNode firstList,WordNode secondList){
            WordNode returnNode = new WordNode("",null);
            WordNode trackingPointer = returnNode;
            while(firstList!=null && secondList!=null){
                if(firstList._word.compareTo(secondList._word) < 0){
                    trackingPointer._next = firstList; firstList=firstList._next;
                }
                else {
                    trackingPointer._next = secondList; secondList=secondList._next
                    ;}
                trackingPointer = trackingPointer._next;
            }
            if (firstList!=null) trackingPointer._next = firstList;
            else if (secondList!=null) trackingPointer._next = secondList;
            return returnNode._next;
            }

        public String toString() {
            String result = "";
            while(_head.getNext() != null){
                _head = _head.getNext();
                result += _head._word + ", ";
            }
            return "List: " + result;
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextList str = new TextList("a b c d e a b");
        System.out.println(str.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to use utilities provided by Java?

Comment: "without Collection.sort". Why?

Comment: A double pivoted quicksort has a very fast average sorting time.

Answer (score 1):

In the past i have made a method to sort strings alphabetically in an array as school HW, so umm here it is:

```
    private void sortStringsAlphabetically(){
    for (int all = 0; all < names.length; all++) {
        for (int i = all + 1; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[all].compareTo(names[i]) > 0) {
                String tmp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[all];
                names[all] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code works for Arrays and specifically for an array of names. You can tweak it to work with the list, it is very simple especially if we consider the wide range of methods in the List interface and all it's implementations.

Cheers.

Comment: That's nice, I will try to convert it into linked list. What is the performance (efficiency) of this code?

Comment: I am not sure what the big O notation is for this piece of code and sadly i am not in a position to calculate it but i assume it is about the same as Selection sorting that is not the most efficient sorting method on earth....
and it seems to be O(n^2) D:
Have a look here to find the O notations known so far: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Yeah, the way he did it with arrays is O(n^2) which is bad. I'm trying to convert it to linked lists with O(n).. pretty hard

Comment: It will sure be tough and i would be intrested to hear the solution to this :D
You may want to have a look here:
http://blog.balfes.net/2010/09/14/which-java-sort-is-faster-mergesort-quicksort-or-arrays-sort/
It has test data for a different sorting algorythms but no Big O notation data D:

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna to have a huge code who gets every first letter of the word and sort them, do it with Collection.sort()

I don't know what is the proplem on Collection.sort() so use it

Here is a short code, that does exactually this what you want to:

```
String test = "hello my name is albert";
test = test.replaceAll(" ", "\n");
String[] te = test.split("\n");
List<String> stlist = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String st : te) {
    stlist.add(st);
}
Collections.sort(stlist);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid using the sort method to have an idea of how it works, but that is just me :- )

Comment: I can't use built in functions. this is what the exercise says

Comment: At least your excersise made that clear... Our teacher asked our CS class to sort an array of strings (See code on my post) and a guy came up with Arrays.sort(T[] array) xD you should have seen the face of the teacher getting red and his eyes being about to fly out as he was looking at the solution... Ehm back on topic now.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding NPE you said it is probably because you are having an null string in head at first and keep adding this in insert method.

```
this._head = new WordNode();
```

Also the adding last element is also not proper.  Just reuse the insert method like below

```
insertNode(text.substring(lastIndex,text.length()));
```

These are the ones I thought having problem when you are converting string to lined list

You can use the below code to handle the first null

```
private void insertNode(String word) {
    if (this._head == null) {
        this._head = new WordNode(word, null);
    } else {
        WordNode newWord = new WordNode(_head._word, _head.getNext());
        _head._word = word;
        _head.setNext(newWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the reusing of the insertNode is really better. but I didn't understand how to fix the null header problem on the first iteration

Comment: Edited answer to handle null

Comment: Thank you, but I noticed another problem. After the insertion, the _head variable points to the last node. I can't figure out how to make it stay as the pointer of the first node and use another points to point the "current" node. You have any ideas?

Comment: Since insert method is inserintg node at start your head node always points to last node inserted. S in current method traverse the nodes until next is null. That is your first node. Otherwise you can modify insert moethod to insert new node at end.